Problem with spawning platforms in Godot 4 when using mouse
I am having quite a unique problem with my game. I want to procedurally generate a set of platforms for the player to jump on. These platforms are supposed to move with the mouse when clicked. But for some reason, the platforms spawn on top of each other, when I hold the mouse button down and move them, making the game unplayable.
Even after adding many conditions and rewriting the algorithms, the problem still persists.
Here is the code for spawning new platforms:
func on_player_on_top(camera_y, old_platform_x):
    # camera_2d.global_position.y = camera_y
    spawn_new_platform(old_platform_x)
    
func spawn_new_platform(old_platform_x):
    var platform_scene = preload("res://source/platforms/regular_platform.tscn")
    var platform = platform_scene.instantiate()
    
    platform.global_position.y = player.global_position.y - 860.0
    var new_platform_x: float
    if old_platform_x > 540:
        new_platform_x = randf_range(0.0, old_platform_x - 300.0)
    else:
        new_platform_x = randf_range(old_platform_x + 300, 1080.0)
    
    platform.global_position.x = new_platform_x
    
    platform.connect("player_on_top", on_player_on_top)
    $Platforms.add_child(platform)

And here is the code for the platforms themselves:
func _physics_process(delta):
    mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("touch"):
        offset.x = get_global_mouse_position().x - global_position.x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("touch"):
        global_position.x = get_global_mouse_position().x - offset.x
        
    #if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        #velocity.x = -speed
    #elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        #velocity.x = speed
    #else:
        #velocity.x = 0
        
    if global_position.x <= -375.0:
        global_position.x = 1080.0 + 375.0
    elif global_position.x >= 1080.0 + 375.0:
        global_position.x = -375.0
        
    move_and_slide()

func _on_top_body_entered(body):
    if !player_touched:
        player_on_top.emit(camera_position.global_position.y, global_position.x)
        player_touched = true


so if you perform the touch action, all existing platforms stack into each other correct?

Yes, that is the case.

in your physics_process you are just checking, if the action is pressed, not what is pressed. Since every platform checks for the touch, all of the are setting their position. You need to add a check, to determine which platform should peform the action. For example: If only the last one should be moving, you could disable physics process for all other platforms. If the platform that is clicked should be moving, you could add a area2d to check, if the click is in this area, or calculate on your own, if the mouse_position is inside your platform on click
